# EclipseLink - issue compiling Query and the state field path cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jpa

When hitting my invoices page sometimes I get this error. The table is in the database, the JPA entity is set up and the query is valid.

If I clean and restart my server most of the time it magically works but as soon as I change anything in the servlet it throws this error again after restarting the server.

I've searched the internet high and low and can't find an answer to why this is happening.

If you have any ideas please let me know.

> Feb 10, 2014 9:49:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with
>   path [##290] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException:
>   /####/###/###/invoices.jsp(16,1) '${ti.teacherInvoiceList}' Error
>   reading 'teacherInvoiceList' on type
>   uk.org.mfsf.dao.TeacherInvoiceLists] with root cause Local Exception
>   Stack:  Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.0.v20140201-f85d864): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException Exception
>   Description: Problem compiling [SELECT i FROM Invoice i WHERE
>   i.invoice.id = :id ].  [14, 32] The abstract schema type 'Invoice' is
>   unknown. [41, 61] The state field path 'm.invoice.id' cannot be
>   resolved to a valid type.     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1614)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1636)
>     at
>   uk.org.mfsf.dao.TeacherInvoiceLists.getTeacherInvoiceList(TeacherInvoiceLists.java:33)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)  at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)    at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)     at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.content.page.page_002dtemplates.invoices_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f1(invoices_jsp.java:418)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.content.page.page_002dtemplates.invoices_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(invoices_jsp.java:392)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.content.page.page_002dtemplates.invoices_jsp._jspService(invoices_jsp.java:103)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
>     at
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.content.page.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f0(index_jsp.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.content.page.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(index_jsp.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.content.page.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:98)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was some sort of local configuration set up issue, unfortunately I can't remember what the solution was, but it's pretty specific to this project.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case the problem was caused by duplicated classes. My project had 2 dependencies (2 JPA projects), in which I used the same package; one of the generated entities had the same name and package in both projects.